# RasterizeLayer in GDAL Java

Tags: buffer, gdal-rasterize

As per the suggestions given by Michael to one of my earlier query (URL given below), I have tried to develop a sample code to perform rasterize using GDAL Java API methods.  I had written based on the Python sample from cookbook.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305164/using-gdal-proximity-function?noredirect=1#comment498883_305164

I am performing rasterize on a shapefile and the above code generates output but image in blank.

publicpublic void rasterizeShp() {

```
    //# Define pixel_size and NoData value of new raster
    int pixel_size = 25;
    int NoData_value = 255;

    gdal.AllRegister();
    org.gdal.ogr.ogr.RegisterAll();
    int bufferDistance = 20;

    String shpFilePath = "C:/img/GLXMABufferRadius.shp";

    //# Open the data source and read in the extent
    DataSource sourceDs = org.gdal.ogr.ogr.Open(shpFilePath,gdalconstConstants.GA_ReadOnly);
    Layer sourceLayer = sourceDs.GetLayer(0);

    SpatialReference sourceSrs = sourceLayer.GetSpatialRef();
    double[] extent = sourceLayer.GetExtent();

    //# Create the destination data source
    double x_res = ((extent[1] - extent[0]) / pixel_size);
    double y_res = ((extent[3] - extent[2]) / pixel_size);
    System.out.println("x_res -------" + x_res +  "y " + y_res );
    int xCor = (int)x_res;
    int yCor = (int)y_res;

    System.out.println("xCor -------" + xCor);
    System.out.println("yCor -------" + yCor);

    String output = "C:/img/myAttrOp2.tif";
    org.gdal.gdal.Dataset target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff").Create(output, xCor, yCor, 1, gdalconst.GDT_Byte);
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform(new double[]{extent[0], pixel_size, 0, extent[2], 0, -pixel_size});
    //target_ds.SetGeoTransform(sourceLayer.GetExtent());
    Band band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1);
    band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value);
    band.FlushCache();

    int[] intArr = {1};

    //# Rasterize
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, intArr, sourceLayer, null);

}
```

Is this the right approach for rasterizing. Also I would like to know the correct way of setting geotransform.  I sometimes get "ERROR 1: Attempt to create 2x0 dataset is illegal, sizes must be larger than zero".

Please let me know if there are corrections to be made in the below code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your sample gave a lot of help in making my solution i hope its not too late so im giving back thanks for the help.

```java
/**
 * // TODO Make safe for multiple calls
 *  !Not safe on multiple calls as drivers are destroyed at the end of the method need so when called with multiple jobs chance of issues.
 * @param geoJson GeoJson string which contain position in degrees for lat lon.
 * @param output Output file to create tiff.
 * @param resX The x resolution of new image
 * @param resY The x resolution of new image
 * @param burnColor The color which the geojson features will be colored in.
 * @param noDataValue The nodata value for geotiff image.
 */
public void createGeoTiffFromGeoJson(String geoJson, File output, int resX, int resY, Color burnColor, int noDataValue)
{
    gdal.AllRegister();
    Driver driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff");
    driver.Register();

    DataSource dataSource = ogr.Open(geoJson);
    Layer layer = dataSource.GetLayer(0);
    final Vector<String> imageCreationOptions = new Vector<>(1);
    imageCreationOptions.add("COMPRESS=LZW");
    Dataset newDateSet = driver.Create(output.getAbsolutePath(), resX, resY, 4, gdalconst.GDT_Byte, imageCreationOptions);
    double[] extent = layer.GetExtent();
    double x_res = ((extent[1] - extent[0]) / resX);
    double y_res = ((extent[3] - extent[2]) / resY);
    newDateSet.SetGeoTransform(new double[]
    {
        extent[0], x_res, 0, extent[3], 0, -y_res
    });
    newDateSet.SetProjection("GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]");
    newDateSet.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(noDataValue);
    newDateSet.GetRasterBand(2).SetNoDataValue(noDataValue);
    newDateSet.GetRasterBand(3).SetNoDataValue(noDataValue);
    newDateSet.GetRasterBand(4).SetNoDataValue(noDataValue);
    newDateSet.GetRasterBand(1).FlushCache();
    newDateSet.GetRasterBand(2).FlushCache();
    newDateSet.GetRasterBand(3).FlushCache();
    newDateSet.GetRasterBand(4).FlushCache();
    int[] band =
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4
    };
    double[] burn =
    {
        burnColor.getRed(), burnColor.getGreen(), burnColor.getBlue(), burnColor.getAlpha()
    };
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(newDateSet, band, layer, burn);
    driver.Deregister();
    org.gdal.gdal.gdal.GDALDestroyDriverManager();
}
```

I needed geo json so your original version of accessing the data source should be fine for the geoTransform refer to [this](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html).

I kind used the gdal command line tools first to rasterize the geojson then tried to replicate the same thing using the java bindings. When I did that I figured out what values should go in the extent using a gdalinfoand comparing the two files generated.

Also i wanted a transparent background so i have a four band image and i couldnt figure out how to get the projection info for the geojson still working on it so hard coded mine but yours might contain it because you use shape files.

If you follow the same process should not be hard to figure it out best of luck.